# Custom Serial Number in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI for rendering data in a grid. In that grid there are certain column whose data is fetched from server side but while rendering I want first column to be serial number. Is there any solution so that I can generate serial number client side keeping server pagination in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowNumber = 0;

    function resetRowNumber(e) {
        rowNumber = 0;
    }

    function renderNumber(data) {
        return ++rowNumber;
    }

    function renderRecordNumber(data) {
        var page = parseInt($("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page()) - 1;
        var pagesize = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize();
        return parseInt(rowNumber + (parseInt(page) * parseInt(pagesize)));
    }

</script>
```

Please check [this](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-add-serial-number-column-in.html) link for full code.

Comment: If above solution is not work for you than please provide your code.